# XAML Bind a TextBox with WebView's current URL

Tags: xaml, c++-cx

I am trying to make a basic browser in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="urlBox"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=webView,Path=Source,Mode=TwoWay}"
             KeyDown="OnUrlEnter" AcceptsReturn="False"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <WebView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="webView"/>
 </Grid>
```

What I want is that when a user click on a link in the `WebView`, the URL `TextBox` is updated accordingly and of course, if user enters the URL and press [Enter] button, the `webView` should navigate to the specified URL but I have already achieved that. I have tried handling `NavigationStarting`, `NavigationCompleted`, `NavigationFailed` (deprecated), `LoadCompleted` (deprecated) but none of them helps me get new URL whenever user click on links in the `WebView`. (The event handlers are only invoked once when I do `webView->Navigate`. Needless to say, `{Binding ElementName=webView,Path=Source,Mode=TwoWay}` does not seem to work.)

What should I do to synchronize the `WebView`'s URL and the `TextBox`? There should be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you could use is.

expose a property

```
private string browserURL;
public string BrowserURL
{
    get{return browserURL;}
    set{ browserURL=value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("BrowserURL");
       }

}

public constructor()
{
    WebBrowser.Navigating += WebBrowser_Navigating;
    this.DataContext= this;
}

private void TechMCaresBrowsercontroll_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
      browserURL=e.Uri;
}
```

XAML Code

```
<TextBox x:Name="urlBox"
         Text="{Binding BrowserURL}"
         KeyDown="OnUrlEnter" AcceptsReturn="False"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

so every time the browser will be navigating to a new URL you exposed property's value would get changed calling NotifyPropertyChanged and would update your textbox.